# Rx Observable pipe handling errors

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, reactive-programming

I have a `submit` routine with a `before` "callback" and a `after` "callback".

Both `before`, `submit` and `after` may perform async requests to backend services.

The three routines should be called sequentially and wrapped around a zip operator to execute further code only once the three routines have completed.

Being a newbie Rx programmer I'm not sure about **how to "pipe" the three routines together**.

**UPDATE 1**

By routine I mean a function.

```
submit() { // same for 'before' and 'after'
  this.backend.methodMakingHttpRequestAndReturningObservable();
}
```

As stated in the question's title, the problem is in the context of Rx Observable used inside Angular in this particular case.

Comment: what do you  mean by routine and callback? can you show an example please?

Comment: What you have try so far ?

Comment: What is exatly 'before' 'after' ? Event ? Observable ? anything else ? We need more code to be able to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`concatMap` **does not subscribe** to the next observable until the previous completes. ([Check this site](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)).

```
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/concatMap';

$before = httpRequest();
$submit = httpRequest();
$after = httpRequest();

const $request = $before.pipe(
  concatMap(beforeResponse => {
    // use beforeResponse whatever you want
    return $submit;
  },
  concatMap(submitResponse => {
    // use submitResponse whatever you want
    return $after;
  })
);

$request.subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),
  err => console.log(`something wrong happen: ${err}`) // if any error occur, this is the place to handle it.
);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try this approach today